# HashMaps for selectively choosing Options

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, hashmap

I am trying to create an application where the user is shown a restaurant.
The user is then able to select what items on the provided menu:

```
HashMap<String, Double> mcDonMenu = new HashMap<>();
         mcDonMenu.put("Cheese Burger", 1.99);
         mcDonMenu.put("Cheese Burger with Bacon", 2.99);
         mcDonMenu.put("Double Cheese Burger", 2.99);
         mcDonMenu.put("Double Cheese Burger with Bacon", 3.99);
         mcDonMenu.put("Vaggie Burger", 2.50);
         System.out.println(mcDonMenu);
```

I have this so far, I have researched this over the last few days and I am coming to Stack overflow for help. I understand how to do everything else, I am also very new to HashMaps. All resources I have looked at do not help with how to selectively choose an item and add the item to a new array or HashMaps to be brought back up later for "checkout".

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: If you have the item name you can do mcDonMenu.get("Cheese Burger") and this will give you the value of 1.99. If you want to iterate over the keys and display you need to do mcDonMenu.keySet() that will provide you with the set of the Strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest you to create an Enum `MenuItem`.

Something like this,

```
public enum MenuItem { 
    CHEESE_BURGER(1.99),
    VEG_BURGER(0.99);
    private double price;
    public MenuItem(double price){ this.price = price; }
    public double getPrice(){
         return this.price;
    }
};
```

Once you construct this, you can have a List of MenuItem, instead of a Map.

Better alternate would be to create a class MenuItem with its attributes. This will help you in long run when you start adding multiple attributes to the MenuItem.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend reading the documentation for [HashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html), however to quickly answer your question. A HashMap will allow you quick access by using the `get()` method, which will take your Key as an argument and return the value.

As an example, in your code `double choice = mcDonMenu.get("Cheese Burger");` will store 1.99 in the variable. The Key is case sensitive, and that is important to remember.

Other useful methods are `.contains()` which can check if something exists in your map and `keySet()` which will return a set of all your keys. All of the methods are available in the documentation I linked